# intersection across multiple dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I have many dictionaries:

```
dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 8}, {'c': 4, 'b': 3}, {'a': 9, 'b': 14}, ...]
```

I want to find out which keys they have in common.

So, `f(dicts) == {'b'}` in this case.

I had assumed

```
set.intersection(*map(dict.keys, dicts))
```

Would work, but I get the error

```
TypeError: descriptor 'intersection' for 'set' objects doesn't apply to a 'dict_keys' object
```

So it looks like `dict.keys` returns a `dict_keys` object, that `set.intersection` refuses to handle.

Is there an equally succinct way to get the collective intersection of some `dict_keys`? Or am I forced to `reduce` with `&`?

```
import functools
set(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, map(dict.keys, dicts)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to map with sth like `lambda x: set(x.keys())`? Can't test rn

Comment: Maybe `set.intersection(*[set(d) for d in dicts])` or `set.intersection(*map(set, dicts))`

Comment: @MarkMeyer very nice! Thank you. Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the dicts directly to `set`s, instead of `dict_keys` objects, which can then be passed to `set.intersetcion()`:

```
dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 8}, {'c': 4, 'b': 3}, {'a': 9, 'b': 14}]
set.intersection(*map(set, dicts))
# {'b'}
```